# Sql Not Compiling Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

i have the above SQL query is not compiling somewhere i lost a truck if you please help me locate the error.

```
SELECT *
       FROM tblWarehouse AS W INNER JOIN (((tblTransactionsSC AS T 
                               LEFT JOIN tblCustomer AS C ON T.tracstID = C.cstID) 
                               INNER JOIN (tblTransactionsSubSC AS TS 
                               LEFT JOIN tblWarehouseItem AS WI 
                               ON TS.trswhiID = WI.whiID) 
                               ON T.traID = TS.trstraID) 
                               ON W.wrhID = T.trawrhID) 
                               LEFT JOIN tblTransactionsSC ON tblStockItemAssignment.siaID = tblTransactionsSC.trasiaID
```

Comment: What error do you get? What database are you actually using? MySQL and SQL Server are *not* the same thing.

Comment: well....theres no select statement

Comment: The Error is Syntax error  @john conde

Comment: That's a really useless response

Comment: it is if i new my syntax error i would have corrected it already... not posting it...@John Conde

Answer (score 3):

Your `JOIN ON` clauses are going haywire; try placing them properly like

```
SELECT w.*
FROM tblWarehouse AS W 
INNER JOIN tblTransactionsSC AS T ON W.wrhID = T.trawrhID
LEFT JOIN tblCustomer AS C ON T.tracstID = C.cstID 
INNER JOIN tblTransactionsSubSC AS TS  ON T.traID = TS.trstraID
LEFT JOIN tblWarehouseItem AS WI ON TS.trswhiID = WI.whiID
LEFT JOIN tblTransactionsSC ON tblStockItemAssignment.siaID = tblTransactionsSC.trasiaID
```